# Recover elements from each cluster generated by scipy dendrogram

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy, dendrogram

I'm building a dendrogram and truncating it to show only the largest 6 clusters. Also, the labeling is done via a simple leaf label function:

```
def llf(id):
   return str(id)

tree = sch.dendrogram(Z, truncate_mode='lastp', 
                      leaf_label_func=llf, p=6, show_contracted=False,
                      show_leaf_counts=False, leaf_rotation=90, 
                      no_labels = False, orientation='right')
```

My output looks like this:

[image]

My goal is to replace the non descriptive labels for the leaves with the minimum value of the members from within that cluster. For example, if the top leaf is the cluster that contains the range from 10 to 1000, then I would like to replace '2468' with 10. The actual logic to replace the ticks in the plot is easy to implement:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mislabels = ["foo" for i in range(7)]
ax.set_xticklabels(mislabels, fontsize=10, rotation=45)
```

Any ideas regarding how to extract the values from within the leaders?

So far I'm able to map each singleton leaf to its cluster using fcluster. However, that only maps my initial 1230 points to a cluster. I need to map the point labeled as '2468' to its cluster and I'm not sure how to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do it

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10,5))
ax = ax.ravel()
# [idx_plot[k]:, idx_plot[k]:]
for k, val in enumerate(linkages['ward']):    
    cluster_local = cluster_labels[val]['ward'][6]    
    leaders = sch.leaders(linkages['ward'][val], cluster_local)
    dates_labels = dict()
    for v, i in enumerate(leaders[1]):
        date_idx = np.where(cluster_local == i)
        dates_labels[leaders[0][v]] = (fechas[val][idx_plot[val]:][date_idx[0][0]].strftime('%y/%m'), fechas[val][idx_plot[val]:][date_idx[0][-1]].strftime('%y/%m'))
    mislabels = [dates_labels[leaders[0][i]][0] + ', ' + dates_labels[leaders[0][i]][1] for i in range(6)]
    yuca = sch.dendrogram(linkages['ward'][val], truncate_mode='lastp', ax=ax[k], leaf_label_func=llf, p=6, show_contracted=False, show_leaf_counts=False,
                          leaf_rotation=0, no_labels=False, orientation = 'right' )
#     ax[k].set_xticklabels(mislabels, fontsize=10, rotation=90)
    ax[k].set_yticklabels(mislabels, fontsize=10, rotation=0)
    ax[k].set_title(val)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]